# Querying location fel in freebase from Google Refine returns error

Tags: freebase, openrefine

I am fairly new to Google (Open) Refine and Freebase, and I am trying to find tutorials (aside from their video) on data augmentation. I have a fairly simple table with states of the US, which would like to augment with population data and other fields. The images below describe the process.

[image: Add column from freebase - population]

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why I get the error?

Is there a way to perform the same operation directly with Freebase, or a good tutorial out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Refine 2.5, Google turned off the APIs that it uses for augmentation from Freebase.

OpenRefine 2.6 which will start alpha/beta testing shortly adds support for the new APIs.

Comment: Thank you Tom! Yes, I am using 2.5. Any idea when the 2.6 will be out? Cheers

Comment: As soon as I stop answering StackOverflow questions and start doing real work. :-) Alpha kits should be out this week.

Comment: Tom, please let me know if there is a distribution list or something. I would love to start using it as soon as it is out, if possible. Cheers

Comment: I'll be announcing it on the OpenRefine list in Google Groups as well as on Twitter (@tfmorris).  Alpha kits went out to the development team a few days ago and I hope to have a kit for wider distribution next week.